# Expected minimum number

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

$X_i$ iid with $P(X_i=j)=p_j$, $j=1, \dots, m$.
$\sum_{j=1}^m p_j = 1$.
Define $N = \min\{n>0:X_n = X_0\}$, compute $E(N)$.

I have two solutions, but different answers:

**Solution 1**

$E(N) = E(N\mid X_1=X_0)P(X_1=X_0) + E(N\mid X_1\neq X_0)P(X_1\neq X_0)$

So $x = 1\cdot y + (1+x)(1-y)$, where $x = E(N), y = P(X_1=X_0) = \sum_{j=1}^m p_j^2$, and thus

$E(N) = 1/y = 1/\sum_{j=1}^m p_j^2$.

**Solution 2**

$E(N) = \sum_{j=1}^m E(N\mid X_0=j)P(X_0=j) = \sum_{j=1}^m 1/p_j \times p_j = m$

I cannot see where is wrong.
Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution 2 is correct.

In Solution 1, you are assuming that $E(N|X_1\ne X_0)=1+EN$, which is not true in general. Indeed, $N$ is the time needed to return to $i$ from a state $i$ -- whereas, on any event of the form $\{X_0=i\ne j=X_1\}$, $N-1$ is the time needed to get to state $i$ from $j\ne i$.

Comment: I see. $E(N\mid X_1 \neq X_0) = 1$ + number of steps needed from $X_1$ to $X_0$. Thanks!